# How to test accelerometer app on ipad retina?

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator, accelerometer, retina-display

I have submitted an Cocos2D accelerometer-based app for the iPad on the App Store.

Apple rejected my app as they said they needed 2x images for the iPad Retina.

So I have added the necessary images, but I don't have an iPad Retina....as you all know you can't test the accelerometer on the iOS Simulator.

So how am I supposed to test the app to ensure it's ok?

Is there any alternative solution?....or the only way is to actually buy the device??
Would really appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/) to get accelerometer events from a real device into the iOS simulator (which you can configure to simulate a retina iPad).

Comment: Hi omz!....thanks for your help. But iSimulate only supports iOS till version 4.1, whereas my app has been created for iOS 6.1.3. Also, I am using Xcode 4.6.1.